# Difference between FILESTREAM and set a path for the file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

I think I know about the basic of these situations.

1) when you insert a `.PDF` file into a database, it will be inside the `.MDF` file:

```
INSERT INTO normal_table(id ,nome_arquivo,arquivo)
SELECT 1,'File_name',bulkcolumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\yeah\Desktop\something.pdf',SINGLE_BLOB) AS ImageSource
```

2)When you create a filestream database, you will be using some folder, inside some driver, to allocate the inserted file, and then I can set the folder to be in another disc with more space:

```
use  Archive 
ON
PRIMARY ( NAME = Arch1,
    FILENAME = 'E:\Filestream_patch\archdat1.mdf'),
FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM( NAME = Arch3,
    FILENAME = 'E:\Filestream_patch\filestream1')
LOG ON  ( NAME = Archlog1,
    FILENAME = 'E:\Filestream_patch\archlog1.ldf')
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FS_Table]
(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UI] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
[FS_Data] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM NULL
)

Use Archive
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FS_Table] ( UI, FS_Data)
VALUES (
NEWID()
,(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\yeah\Desktop\something.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Image001)
);
GO
```

But what about developers that use something like, set a `path` to the file, and then use it inside c# code?

```
CREATE TABLE Example
( id int, file_path varchar(500))
```

What is the difference between using this `path` strategy, and filestream? How can I evaluate this situation, to know what can be better for the company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you back up the database that hosts your 'Example' table, you backed up the string of characters `c:\asohdo\ash\file.pdf` (that **point** to your pdf file) but you didn't backup the actual PDF file.

FILESTREAM data is included in your database backup (unless you specifically *exclude* it).

Check out the [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) Overview for more information